# How to compute the first Fridays of each month given a list of dates as DateTime object in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Suppose I have a `DateTimeIndex` object in Python stored as `trading_days`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-07',
               '2014-01-08', '2014-01-09', '2014-01-10', '2014-01-13',
               '2014-01-14', '2014-01-15',
               ...
               '2017-12-15', '2017-12-18', '2017-12-19', '2017-12-20',
               '2017-12-21', '2017-12-22', '2017-12-26', '2017-12-27',
               '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1007, freq=None)
```

I want to compute the first Friday of each month in this DateTime object. My desired output is another DateTime object with these dates for the first Fridays.

My attempt was the following:

```
all_fridays = trading_days[trading_days.day_name() == 'Friday']
first_fridays = all_fridays[np.remainder(np.arange(len(all_fridays)), 4) == 0]
```

But of course this code will fail if, for example, a certain month has 5 Fridays.
For example, the output I get from the code above is

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-03', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28', '2014-03-28',
               '2014-05-02', '2014-05-30', '2014-06-27', '2014-08-01',
               '2014-08-29', '2014-09-26', '2014-10-24', '2014-11-21',
               '2014-12-19', '2015-01-16', '2015-02-13', '2015-03-13',
               '2015-04-17', '2015-05-15', '2015-06-12', '2015-07-17',
               '2015-08-14', '2015-09-11', '2015-10-09', '2015-11-06',
               '2015-12-04', '2016-01-15', '2016-02-12', '2016-03-11',
               '2016-04-15', '2016-05-13', '2016-06-10', '2016-07-08',
               '2016-08-05', '2016-09-02', '2016-09-30', '2016-10-28',
               '2016-11-25', '2016-12-23', '2017-01-20', '2017-02-17',
               '2017-03-17', '2017-04-21', '2017-05-19', '2017-06-16',
               '2017-07-14', '2017-08-11', '2017-09-08', '2017-10-06',
               '2017-11-03', '2017-12-01', '2017-12-29'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

January 2014 is prone to the error I just described. And then everything gets screwed.

How can I do it in a efficient way? I feel that `Pandas` should have something like that already built in but I couldn't find it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure how to re-create you sample DatetimeIndex, but we'll start with a simple `bdate_range`.

Subset to Friday then drop duplicates on the Year-Month period

```
import pandas as pd
trading_days = pd.bdate_range('2014-01-02', freq='C', periods=1007, weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri')

fridays = trading_days[trading_days.dayofweek == 4]
fridays = fridays[~fridays.to_period('M').duplicated()]

#DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-03', '2014-02-07', '2014-03-07', '2014-04-04',
#               '2014-05-02', '2014-06-06', '2014-07-04', '2014-08-01',
#               ...
#               '2017-05-05', '2017-06-02', '2017-07-07', '2017-08-04',
#               '2017-09-01', '2017-10-06', '2017-11-03'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you will find out the first Friday of the array, then the following logic can help you.

Lets say the first Friday was on 2014-01-03, then check the digit at 4th position from the end( i am considering '-' as a position ), now add 28 to the current index. If the received date also has the same digit at the 4th position from last as that of the previous one, then add 7 more to the index and that index will be the first Friday of the next month, else the index obtained by adding 28 will the first Friday of next month.

Here you are not required to check the 5th position as the last 3 months, i.e. 10, 11 and 12 , all have last digit different from their predecessors.

All the above explanation can be easily implemented using if else conditions in pyhton.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that will extract the first Friday of each month (or fourth Thursday of each month, or...) from a pandas DatetimeIndex.  It's an excuse to use the `itertools.groupby()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

def get_one_date_per_month(dates, rank='first', day_name='Friday'):
    rank_to_idx = {'first': 0, 'second': 1, 'third': 2, 'fourth': 3, 'last': -1}
    idx = rank_to_idx[rank]
    dates = [d
             for d in dates
             if d.day_name() == day_name]
    
    filtered_dates = []
    for k, g in groupby(dates, key=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m')):
        t = list(g)
        filtered_dates.append(t[idx])
        
    return filtered_dates
```

Use the function like this:

```
# use your list of trading days, or `dates` for illustration:
dates = pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', end='2017-12-31', freq='D')

get_one_date_per_month(dates)[:3]

# results are:
[Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-07 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2014-03-07 00:00:00', freq='D')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is better than the other answers already posted.  But I started with the dates in a `DatetimeIndex` as per your question:

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('2014-01-02', '2017-12-19'))  # some dates
dates_by_month = index.groupby(index.to_period("M"))    
first_fridays = pd.Series({period: dates[dates.weekday == 4][0]
                           for period, dates in dates_by_month.items()})
first_fridays.head()

2014-01   2014-01-03
2014-02   2014-02-07
2014-03   2014-03-07
2014-04   2014-04-04
2014-05   2014-05-02
Freq: M, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```